# VSCode IntelliSense Autocompletion doesn't add custom Type with already existing module

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete, intellisense

I have an *export.js* file, which looks like this:

```
function myFunction1() {
    //something
}

function myFunction2() {
    //something
}

function myFunction3() {
    //something
}


module.exports = {
    myFunction1: myFunction1,
    myFunction2: myFunction2,
}
```

*myFunction3()* is only there so that I can test IntelliSense. This works fine in another *js* file, where I import the *export.js*.

Now I want to include a *.d.ts* file to extend the list of Autocompletion hints in a way like:

```
//I need to use external libraries that don't
//have an easy way of importing functions, hence a decleration File
declare module test {
    export function myFunction4(a: string): string;
    export function myFuntcion5(a: number): number;
}
```

The base file should look something like this:

```
let test = require('./export.js');

test.myFunction1(); //to myFunction5
```

The problem now: When I do not import the *export.js* file I can see *myFunction4* and *myFunction5* through IntelliSense. But when I do import it, I am only able to see *myFunction1* and *myFunction2*. How can I combine these two librarys for Intellisense?